# Photoshop Free Transform Constrain Proportions in Photoshop CC 2019

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform

It appears that the latest Adobe update (Photoshop CC 2019) has changed the way proportions are done. Previously I would use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Drag to constrain proportions in **Free Transform** mode. Photoshop now defaults to only Drag to keep proportions in Free Transform and uses <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Drag to size at any ratio.

I could manual click the proportion lock in the toolbar but after more than a decade of using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Drag, it's really cumbersome to have to take this extra step and it's disrupting the workflow that's been ingrained in my head since I started using Ps.

**Has anyone found a way to enable <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Drag to constrain proportions in the latest Photoshop CC 2019?**

Comment: FYI, instead of manually clicking proportion lock, you can just drag the transform box and it defaults to keep proportion. They just reversed the function so shift + drag is to do free form and only dragging keeps proportion.

Comment: @AndrewH, I saw that in the link you posted. Just doesn't make sense for me since Photoshop isn't the only software I work in and Shift + Drag is the standard for everything else too. Plus, old habits die hard ;)

Comment: Adobe has had a history of making stupid "upgrades" but this has to be the worst in my 15+ years using it.  Now, some objects are constrained and others are not.  Who thought this was a good idea?  ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From Adobes Blog: [What's new in Photoshop CC](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/whats-new.html#user-experience-improvements)

> To revert to the legacy transform behavior, do the following:
>
> Use Notepad (Windows) or a text editor on Mac OS to create a plain
>   text file (.txt). Type the text below in the text file:
>
> `TransformProportionalScale 0`
>
> Save the file as `PSUserConfig.txt` to your Photoshop settings folder:
>
> **Windows**: [Installation Drive]:\Users[User
>   Name]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2019\Adobe Photoshop CC
>   2019 Settings\
>
> **macOS**: //Users/[User Name]/Library/Preferences/Adobe
>   Photoshop CC 2019 Settings/

Comment: And this is under a heading "Usability improvements". Brilliant.

Comment: One more reason I'm so happy I'm still using CS6.

Comment: @AndrewH, thanks for the quick answer! I implemented this fix and it works. +1 √

Comment: @Vincent, I agree...I still run CS6 on my personal computers. I've had zero problems with my "out of the box" software, whereas my subscription experience with CC (on work computers) is riddled with these types of fixes.

Comment: I have found another irritating functional change. I used to be able to select a group label and modify all items in that group. Unless I merge the group, I can't get that to happen. Also, I select a layer to modify and, as I begin, another layer becomes active instead. I am forced to **lock** layers to prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 2):

I found this thread because I had the same issue. The thing I've just realised is that you don't need the modifier key - the free transform automatically constrains the proportions...

Comment: I recovered my account just to be able to upvote this.
I don't know why someone downvoted this answer. It is the correct answer for anyone who doesn't want to have to mess about in some config file.

Answer (score -1):

On macOS, it's now <kbd>Control</kbd> that replaces <kbd>Shift</kbd> in that case.